# Mediawiki <source> tag is not coloring my code section

Tags: syntax-highlighting, mediawiki

I have a small wiki using **MediaWiki 1.26.2** for personal use, within in one article with this section of text:

```
<source enclose=div lang=php>
    $wgGroupPermissions['*']['createaccount'] = false;
</source>
```

And it is showing the next result:

[image: syntaxhighlight without coloring]

**Instead of this**:

[image: syntaxhighlight with coloring]

I mean, **is formatted but without coloring** at all, my understanding is that it should be colorful regardless the skin the wiki is using, so is there a configuration that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Seems there are still the same problems with *SyntaxHighlight_GeSHi*  on *MediaWiki 1.32.*
Alternative is: [Highlightjs](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Highlightjs_Integration)
(it uses js for syntax highlihting)

It works out of box, even not necessary changing previously defining code syntax from *SyntaxHighlight_GeSHi*.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax [highlighter extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SyntaxHighlight#Installation) is *bundled with* recent MediaWiki installations, but not installed by default. You need to enable it in your LocalSettings.php, like this (for MediaWiki 1.24 and newer):

```
wfLoadExtension( 'SyntaxHighlight_GeSHi' );
```

Comment: I already did this @leo but the problem is that it shows the code formatted in the right way, with the border but not wit colors, and the same code is properly colored in another wiki using the same extension and the same text.

Comment: Are there any differences in the CSS styling?

Comment: Never mind, I solved the problem, please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solved the problem, I'm posting the solution just in case someone else gets the same issue. I have my Wiki hosted in godaddy.com and as part of the service you can install Application *out the box*, one of them is MediaWiki, which already has the *SyntaxHighlight* extension installed.

For some reason I don't have clear enough, this extension was not working properly, so I decided to install the extension by my own from [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:ExtensionDistributor/SyntaxHighlight_GeSHi) and this time it worked like a charm.

Comment: For me it didn't work. I even tried past and master versions. Still! :(